# Short if statement not showing any output

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I am trying to autofill form input data if it is set.

Unfortunately, it looks like my if statement is not working at all. I mean it doesn't show anything, no matter if its true or false.

```
<input type="text" value="<?php (isset($formData->fname)) ? 'ok' : 'error'; ?>" name="fname">
```

The `value` always looks like this:

[image]

I was also trying this way but it isn't working:

```
<?php (isset($formData->fname)) ? echo 'ok'; : echo 'error'; ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you've missed echo -))

```
<?php echo (isset($formData->fname)) ? 'ok' : 'error'; ?>
```

Comment: Oh, I feel ashamed right now. I was trying this way: `<?php  (isset($formData->fname)) ? echo 'ok' : echo 'error'; ?>` but it wasnt working haha

Comment: in php, operation/function should precede the ternary block. such - `o <- e1? e2 : e3`. o can be a function, like echo, print etc., or variable like $my_var. in first case the result will be passed as an argument, in second case the result will be assigned to var.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `echo` to print result or `{{ }}`:

```
<input type="text" value="{{ isset($formData->fname) ? 'ok' : 'error' }}">
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not writing the value, use the = opening tag or echo

```
<input type="text" value="<?= (isset($formData->fname)) ? 'ok' : 'error'; ?>" name="fname">
```

or

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo (isset($formData->fname)) ? 'ok' : 'error'; ?>" name="fname">
```